# Complex django db ordering based on FK properties

Tags: python, mysql, django

I have the following two models:

```
class OrderItem(models.Model):
    order = models.ForeignKey(Order, related_name='items')
    title = models.ForeignKey(Title, related_name='order_items')

class OrderNotes(models.Model):
    order_item = models.ForeignKey('OrderItem', blank=True, null=True)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
```

How would I sort `OrderItem`s by the most recent `OrderNote` that is active?

In pseudo_code:

```
OrderItem.objects.order_by('ordernotes_set.order_by('is_active', '-timestamp'))
```

?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you could use annotations to handle this fairly easily.
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/aggregation/#following-relationships-backwards

```
from django.db.models import Max
OrderItems.annotate(newest_note_time=Max('ordernotes__timestamp'))
    .order_by('-ordernotes__is_active', '-newest_note_time')
```

Comment: Doesn't look like this works. Also, this doesn't take into account `is_active`.

Comment: Added the import for the Max() function.  It should work.  I've done similar annotations before on timestamps for ordering.  I don't have access to a python environment right now for testing, but look at the docs for annotations and aggregations.  You should be able to setup a second annotation for is_active and order by that as well.